# Jquery Date Calculations JQUERY4U

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying tom implement the following script which looks like a great date calculation library built on top of Jquery.

http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/datetime-functions-complete-listing/

My basic knowledge of Jquery and Javascript isn't sufficient to get this working so I'm looking for some help with the usage.

I've loaded the file in the header of the page I want to use it and tried unsuccessfully to call the functions like:

```
JQUERY4U.DATETIME.futureDateDays(1);
DATETIME.futureDateDays(1);
futureDateDays(1);
```

And an assortment of other attempts just doesn't seem to work.  I know I'm probably missing something easy.

My goal is to set a variable to the result of the datetime function.

Also, it would be great if you could provide examples for the usage of the date format portion of the script.

I know some of you Jquery and Javascript ninjas will be able to figure this out in under 90 seconds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but that thing is a joke. First - nowhere in the code is jQuery actually used, although they set it up to localize jQuery. Second - the fact that it is in a self executing function (notice how all the code is inside of ";(function($){})(jQuery);") means that none of it is exposed to the rest of your code. That's why you get undefined errors when trying to do something like "JQUERY4U.DATETIME" or anything. Actual jQuery plugins use this structure so that they local jQuery and then extend it to accompany the plugin. This isn't a plugin in any way

Comment: and the only thing it really does is make it so you can call "JQUERY4UFormat" on a Javascript Date object because of this line "Date.prototype.JQUERY4UFormat = this.format;". All that does is allow you to get a date in a specific format, as specified in the "format" function there.

Comment: Any suggestion on another script I can use? I need to be able to calculate the difference in days between two dates and I need to be able to calculate a date in the future based on a number of days to add.  I want to do this in javascript as I will be converting my application language in the near future.

Comment: Are those the only two things you need done? I'll write them up for you

Comment: That would be awesome.  Yeah, those are really the only two things I need, and if it could return the date in d/m/y format that would be great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsFiddle that should have what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/dKGkY/1/

There are three functions that you would need, and hopefully there's enough in the examples to explain what they do. You can obviously change whatever you need for your requirements, but hopefully this is what you need! Let me know if you need helping modifying or using them.

Comment: No problem. Is that everything you need?

Comment: For now it seems to be doing all I need - I added a lastdayofmonth function, but using your code i was able to figure out how to do that pretty easy.  Thanks again!